# Get length of subArray in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON element:

```
json = [
        {
            "category": "Electronic",
            "param": "param1",
            "subMenu": [
                {
                    "subCategory": "Audio & Hifi",
                    "param": "param1-1",
                    "subMenu2": [
                        {
                            "type": "JVC",
                            "param": "param1-1-1"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Kennwood",
                            "param": "param1-1-2"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Sony",
                            "param": "param1-1-3"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Blaupunkt",
                            "param": "param1-1-4"
                        }
                    ]
                }]}]
```

and want to retrieve the length of the subArray subMenu and subMenu2 to implement it in a function. I didn't found an accurate solution yet.

My approach with `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)` and `for (var i = 0; i < subMenu.length; i++)` didn´t work accurately. The length was restricted by the length of the top array.

See it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/pp4t9nw2/4/

Does anyone have an idea how to solve that?

Comment: please add the wanted result. what should happen if there are more entries in `submenu` and their sub menues? btw, you are dealing with an array, not with [JSON](http://json.org/). this is always a string.

Comment: `json[0]["subMenu"].length` and `json[0]["subMenu"][0]["submenu2"].length`

Comment: Show us what you tried. You seem to use `i` 2 times.

Comment: If you nest the for-loops make sure you don't reuse `i`.

Comment: I added jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pp4t9nw2/4/ to see it in action.

Comment: If you have control over this structure, I would _strongly_ recommend changing the naming.  Instead of `subMenu2`, use `subMenu`, then you could write a simple function that looks for "submenus" in the array(s) and reports the length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use different variables for loop in submenus, for instance:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < json[i].subMenu.length; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < json[i].subMenu[j].subMenu2.length; k++) {
            let item = json[i].subMenu[j].subMenu2[k];
            // item.type available
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're after here but if you want to know how many elements are in the top level subMenu then json[0].subMenu.length will do it.

You can loop through json (note that you've called it json, not array as your code suggests) and then for each one of the elements in there, you can get the json[iterator].subMenu.length

If you then want to loop through subMenu2 you need a second loop but make sure you use a different iterator variable.

Answer (score -2):

In this example you need to adress the subMenu2 proberly.
For example:
json.subMenu.subMenu2.length

But subMenu doesnt really have a length, since only subMenu2 is in it.

Hope i could help.

Comment: `json` is an array, `json.submenu` will throw `undefined`. Same for `submenu` which is also an array.

Comment: if `subMenu2` is inside `subMenu` then it will have a length of at least **1** as it has something inside it right?

Comment: @NewToJS Should be.

Comment: Well no. If subMenu is an array, then `subMenu.subMenu2` is undefined. Calling `subMenu.subMenu2.length` will inevitably throw `Error: cannot get length of undefined`

Comment: @Christopher should be and it is.... check for yourself `json[0].subMenu.length` and use `json[0].subMenu[0].subMenu2.length` to get the length of `subMenu2`

Comment: ah, "it" will have a length, you were talking about `subMenu`, not `subMenu2`. Yes, that's right then.

Comment: @JeremyThille Yeah your right, first answer on stackoverflow. I try to check better next time. :D